# Activate Excel sheet in VBA without navigating to the worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to activate Excel worksheet from VBA without actually going away from the worksheet from which the macro was launched ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can directly run the desired code in the New Worksheet by using the `with` command

```
With Sheets("Sheet2") 'Sheet2 is the new sheet
    Debug.Print .Range("A1")
    'Run your desired code here.
End With
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

`ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Activate`

This will make the desired worksheet be set as active. Note that if you do not disable `Application.ScreenUpdating` first, as mentioned in the other answer here, the worksheets will visibly jump around so that the active worksheet is being displayed.

However, I must ask, why do you need to activate the worksheet? If you want to run some commands against cells located on that worksheet, you can do so without activating the worksheet first:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)

ws.Range("A1").Value = "Hello world"
```

This snippet will insert "Hello world" into the cell `A1` on the second worksheet in your workbook - no worksheet activation required.

Comment: I just wanted to make the code more concise by declaring an active spreadsheet and then addressing its ranges without having to explicitly write the ws prefix. But given that setting screen update to false is the only way around to jump between spreadsheets, I end up using your solution, because screenupdating disables statusbar update.

Comment: Using explicitly declared references is always a plus, even if it makes the work more "tedious". In the long run, it is a good habit to have - for larger bases of code or for projects that reference a multitude of sheets, it is practically a necessity. Also note that disabling `Application.ScreenUpdating` still lets you do things with the statusbar.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `Application.ScreenUpdating` property to `false`,and after your work is done, recover it to `true`.
Refer to the example:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193498.aspx